# can not focus children of skinnableContainer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, setfocus

I have a custom component extends from skinnableContainer and only has two NumericSteppers.
I explicitly set focus to my component like `myComponent.setFocus()`. It sets focus to first stepper which is correct, but when I press TAB to move focus to next stepper it moves focus to the next Component.

I set `tabEnabled = true` and `tabChildren=true` of the component, still no luck.
How could I set focus to next stepper on pressing TAB?

Comment: I tried this solution, but problem still persists :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the [`focusEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#focusEnabled) property is also set to true. You could also programatically set the [`tabIndex`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#tabIndex) property for each tab.